# no such file to load -- rcov/rcovtask issue in ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have setup existing project first time in my system where `ruby 1.8.7 and rails 2.3.8`

When i try to install gems using `rake gems:install`

I get error `no such file to load -- rcov/rcovtask`

What actual problem i dont know

Have any one idea?

Answer (score 0):

Run:

`gem install rcov`

then you'll be good to go.